# ANTLR Beginner => grammar question

Tags: antlr, grammar

I'm a beginner using ANTLR. I'm just doing the following for test purposes and try to understand the way it works and produce errors:

`INTEGER_NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+;`
`integer_number: INTEGER_NUMBER;`
`decimal_number: (integer_number '.' integer_number) | ('.' integer_number);`
`regular_number: decimal_number|integer_number;`

I have the following warning on the "regular_number" rule : Decision can match input such as "INTEGER_NUMBER '.' INTEGER_NUMBER" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input.

What exactly does it means ?

---

Ok I have edited this post to include the code that reproduce this error

`program :(price)*;`

`INTEGER_NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+;`
`INFO_PRICE : 'OLD PRICE';`
`FRACTION_NUMBER :  '1/16'|'1/8'|'3/16'|'1/4'|'5/16'|'3/8'|'7/16'|'1/2'|'9/16'|'5/8'|'11/16'|'3/4'|'13/16'|'7/8'|'15/16';`
`CURRENCY : 'EUR'|'USD'|'GBP';`

`integer_number : INTEGER_NUMBER    ;`
`decimal_number : (integer_number? '.') integer_number  ;`
`fraction_number : (integer_number ((' ')+))? FRACTION_NUMBER;`
`regular_number : decimal_number|integer_number ;`
`numerical_number :regular_number|fraction_number;`
`non_numerical_number : INFO_PRICE ((' ')*) ('+'|'-') ((' ')*)(numerical_number)((' ')*) CURRENCY;`

`price  : numerical_number |non_numerical_number;`

`WS :  (' ' | '\t' | '\f')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};`
`NL :('\r' '\n' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};`

and the error know is this one

error(201): /ANTLR - Tuto 1/src/Test.g:37:2: The following alternatives can never be matched: 2
 |---> : decimal_number|integer_number  ;

Comment: There's nothing wrong with grammar you posted. Generating a lexer and parser on the command line, and using ANTLRWorks (1.4), don't produce the error you posted.

Comment: are there some more rules after that?  I suspect there are.  are you testing for start and end of tokens?

Comment: Aside from the question, you can change `decimal_number: (integer_number '.' integer_number) | ('.' integer_number);` to `decimal_number: (integer_number? '.' integer_number);`: Same thing, but it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you're all right, I extracted this piece of code from my example as the warning was posted on this particular line. In fact, it seems that the warning appears because of another rule... I will try to see which one and post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, there's nothing wrong with the grammar you posted.

The error you mention occurs with the following grammar:

```
grammar Test;

regular_number
  :  decimal_number
  |  integer_number
  ;

integer_number
  :  INTEGER_NUMBER
  ;

decimal_number
  :  integer_number '.' integer_number
  |  '.' integer_number
  |  integer_number                      // <- I added this one
  ;

INTEGER_NUMBER 
  :  '0'..'9'+ 
  ;
```

When the parser tries to match a `regular_number` for the input string `"123"`, it does not know which alternative to choose. Both `decimal_number` and `integer_number` match `"123"`. Hence the error message:

```
... using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

### EDIT

From within the `regular_number` rule, the string `"123.456"` could be parsed as:

```
integer_number decimal_number
123            .456
```

or as:

```
decimal_number
123.456
```

Why not define a DECIMAL_NUMBER in the lexer:

```
DECIMAL_NUMBER
  :  INTEGER_NUMBER '.' INTEGER_NUMBER
  |  '.' INTEGER_NUMBER
  ;
```

?

That should fix that problem.

There are more issues though:

```
numerical_number 
  :  fraction_number
  |  regular_number
  ;
```

when the rule above tries to handle input like `"2 1/8"`, the `2` from it could be a part of your `fraction_number` including the `1/8`, but it could also be handled as a `regular_number` followed by a `fraction_number`.

Also, you shouldn't define spaces inside your parser rules, you've put them on the HIDDEN channel in the lexer, so they won't be "seen" by the parser.

Having said all that, this would be a possible alternative grammar that probably does what you want:

```
program 
  :  price* EOF
  ;

price 
  :  numerical_number 
  |  non_numerical_number
  ;

numerical_number
  :  FRACTION_NUMBER
  |  DECIMAL_NUMBER
  |  INTEGER_NUMBER
  ;

non_numerical_number 
  :  INFO_PRICE ('+' | '-') (INTEGER_NUMBER FRACTION_NUMBER | numerical_number) CURRENCY
  ;

DECIMAL_NUMBER
  :  INTEGER_NUMBER '.' INTEGER_NUMBER
  |  '.' INTEGER_NUMBER
  ;

FRACTION_NUMBER 
  :  '1/16' | '1/8' | '3/16' | '1/4' | '5/16' | '3/8' | '7/16' | '1/2' | 
     '9/16' | '5/8' | '11/16' | '3/4' | '13/16' | '7/8' | '15/16'
  ;

INTEGER_NUMBER  
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;

INFO_PRICE
  : 'OLD PRICE'
  ;

CURRENCY
  : 'EUR' | 'USD' | 'GBP'
  ;

WS 
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\f' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

### EDIT II

> > Also, you shouldn't define spaces inside your parser rules, you've 
> >     put them on the HIDDEN channel in the lexer, so they won't be "seen" 
> >     by the parser.
>
> the thing being, how will the lexer make the difference 
>   beetween 1011 1/16 and 101 11/16 for example ?

When encountering the (sub) string `1011 1/16`, `1011` is tokenized as an `INTEGER_NUMBER`, the space is put on the  HIDDEN channel (and is therefor not present in the token-stream that is being passed to the parser), and `1/16` is tokenized as a `FRACTION_NUMBER`.

For `101 11/16` the same applies: `101` is a `INTEGER_NUMBER` and `11/16` a `FRACTION_NUMBER`.

To emphasize: when you put spaces and line breaks on a different channel (like the HIDDEN channel), they are not present in the token stream that the parser operates on. So it makes no sense to use these tokens in parser rules: they're never going to be matched.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you're all right, I extracted this piece of code from my example as the warning was posted on this particular line. In fact, it seems that the warning appears because of another rule... I will try to see which one and post the code.

Comment: @BlackLabrador, you're welcome. I assume you now understand when such an error occurs, right? If you're still not sure where the error lies in your grammar, please edit your original question and post the entire grammar. Thanks!

Comment: Bart, I have edited the post and tried to put the version that produce the error

Comment: Many thanks for your highlights ! your comments are very precise and precious!!!!

Comment: <blockquote> Also, you shouldn't define spaces inside your parser rules, you've put them on the HIDDEN channel in the lexer, so they won't be "seen" by the parser.</blockquote> => the thing being, how will the lexer make the difference beetween 1011 1/16 and 101 11/16 for example ?

Comment: In fact I realized that (one more time) I asked an unclear question and sorry for that. The rule I had in mind was I'm defining in my code `FRACTION :(('0'..'9')+ ' '+  FRACTION_NUMBER);` to express number like 101 11/16. If I don't specify ' ' between `'0'..'9'` and `FRACTION_NUMBER` how could the parser make the difference between 1011 1/16 and 101 11/16. In Edit II, it's really clear that there can't be any confusion with this grammar

Comment: @BlackLabrador, I see what you mean. In that case, the space is part of the entire token. But spaces that are matched by your `WS` rule are never "seen" by the parser, so you can't use literal spaces (or line breaks) in any of the parser rules.

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted means there are two rules that match certain input, in your case the input `INTEGER_NUMBER '.' INTEGER_NUMBER`. However, as Bart commented, the grammar you posted does not have that problem. Are you sure the error comes from the exact thing you posted?

Comment: Hi Jorn, apparently the warning is caused by another rule that I added but the compiler underlined this particular line. I have modified so many times the grammar since that I can't even reproduce the error !